# Add functions to playerglobal.swc or allow compiler to pass own functions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, sdk

Im adding lot of simple functions to prototypes of top level objects ( Object , Array , String ...) and have 2 questions :

Is possible to add functions to top level's classes in compile-time ?

If not , is there a way to allow this functions to compile ? 
I dont like to turn off strict mode , i try and its not a good idea .

ex:

```
string.removeWhiteSpace();
string.sliceStr("." , "end");
textField.scrollBottom();
```

this return compile-time error , cause there is no such function , i have to write it in braces :

```
string["removeWhiteSpace"]();
string["sliceStr"]("." , "end");
textField["scrollBottom"]();
```

and i like to aviod it )

Comment: edited your code so it displayed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right way to deal with this problem. Messing with the prototypes in AS3 is a hack, so you need hackish techniques to make it work.

Another way would be to cast your strings and arrays to `Object` before calling the methods.

An even better way would be to not mess with the prototypes of top level objects and implement utility classes like Adobe does - StringUtil, ArrayUtil, etc.

Comment: I working with prototypes for long time and never have any problem , only is this what i write in question , right now im calling on begging function that add to prototypes all functions and then i run rest code.

Comment: There's no such function, it's simply not possible to work in a clean way with prototypes in AS3. Still, I wonder why you absolutely want to work with prototypes? It makes your life more difficult, your code cluttered with hacks, and probably slower, and you don't benefit from compile time checking. Using a utility class would be more efficient and far cleaner.

Comment: I have not idea why You think that functions in prototypes may be slower and with hacks . And about compile-time checking - that is what i asking for , is that possible to add this functions to playerglobal.swc or any other way ...

Answer (score 1):

The String class uses the attribute "final" which means it can not be overridden.
So to answer your question no you can not override it in anyway.
This is usually done on top level class for performance issues.
Object class uses an attribute type of "dynamic"
All classes that don't declare an explicit base class extend the built-in Object class.

The Array class also uses "dynamic"

As for your example.

```
string.removeWhiteSpace()
```

you could do

```
string.split(" ").join('')
```

and that would achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: no , You totaly dont get what i mean  :] with white space its just example . 
I know that i cannot override string , thay why im adding functions to prototypes and asking for other way to do it .